# Levenshtein distance to match a column of text in df1 changed to codes using metaphone with a column of place names in df2 being coded

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes:- df1 contains a column of sentences (30000 length) describing many things like:

((my holiday will start next June i will travel to south Africa after that will see my mom in Jordan, then i return back England))

I applied the metaphone algorithm to df1 for each sentence using the following code:-

```
df1['metaphone'] = df1['text'].apply(lambda x:' '.join([jellyfish.metaphone(i) for i in x.split()]))
```

a new column added to df1 is the text code of the sentence:-
((M HLT WL STRT NKST JN I WL TRFL T S0 AFRK AFTR 0T WL S M MM IN JRTN 0N I RTRN BK ENKLNT))

the output of df1 is four columns(( text, metaphone, matched code, country))

the df2 has a column of names of countries and cities (480 length).
A new column added to df2 is the code of these names using the metaphone algorithm.

df2

country          metaphone

Abu Dhabi        AB THB
Abuja               ABJ
Accra               AKKR
Adamstown           ATMSTN
Addis Ababa         ATSABB

what I need is to find a match between the two data frames using only the coded columns to identify a country name match in the sentence of df1 in df2.
in the example three location names exists using the levenshtien distance to find a match of the three countries by taking each token in a row of df1 and rolling through coded countries column in df2 and show the matched country.
this process should show the codded token or tokens (if there are more than a match) in a list in df1, and then merge it with the real name of the country
the desired output of the previous sentence should look like this:-
matched code                 country

[S0 AFRK, JRTN, ENKLNT]    [South Africa, Jourdan, England]

if anyone could help I really would appreciate the help.

Comment: Can you edit your question showing examples of your inputs (df1 and df2), and your desired output please?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have edited the input and the desired output I hope it is clear now